# Hit ctrl-c during a pip install of spacy, now getting error when attempt to install again

Tags: python, pip, spacy

I am trying to install spacy. I am on CentOS Linux

```
!pip install -U spacy
```

in a jupyter notebook and everything was working fine. During the installation, I realized I intended to include the --user command since I intended to install for my user only, so I hit ctrl-c. At this point the installation is incomplete.

Trying to install the package again with pip is now giving me an error, regardless of whether I include the --user flag. I think the error, below, is related to the incomplete build. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
Collecting spacy
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 
215, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", 
line 335, in run 
wb.build(autobuilding=True)
File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in 
build
self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 
380, in prepare_files
ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 
620, in _prepare_file
session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 809, 
in unpack_url
unpack_file_url(link, location, download_dir, hashes=hashes)
File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 715, 
in unpack_file_url
unpack_file(from_path, location, content_type, link)
File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", 
line 599, in unpack_file
flatten=not filename.endswith('.whl')
File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", 
line 484, in unzip_file
zip = zipfile.ZipFile(zipfp, allowZip64=True)
File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 770, in __init__
self._RealGetContents()
File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 811, in _ 
RealGetContents
raise BadZipfile, "File is not a zip file"
BadZipfile: File is not a zip file`
```

Comment: do you see any relevant processes or jobs when you do `jobs` or `ps aux | grep pip` ?

Comment: You could also try disabling the pip cache by setting the `--no-cache-dir` flag.

Comment: The wheel file might be corrupt or incomplete. Try `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall spacy`

Comment: That sounds right. Before I post this as an answer: here is what worked for me. I went to 
    $HOME/.cache/pip 
and deleted the contents of http/ and wheels/. I tried to test the answers above but apparently reproducing this error requires hitting ctrl-c at the right place. So long as this won't cause big problems for someone else trying to solve the same problem, I'll post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. A solution that worked for me was to go to $HOME/.cache/pip and delete the contents of http/ and wheels/